How do I create an Azure VPN Gateway with the basic sku?
When attempting to create a VNet Gateway for a site-to-site VPN on East US 2, I don't see the Basic sku (as described in the Azure Pricing Calculator for a VPN Gateway)... I only see VpnGw1-5 + AZ options. Is there a way to create a basic sku VPN Gateway?
